# Где выкладывать информацию?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

В Инете мало информации по LyX на русском языке.  Я же эту прогру изучил неплохо. Русскоязычные пользователи (подавляющее большинство) считают эту прогру плохой, хуже других редакторов LaTeX якобы из-за ограниченного функционала. Но это не так. И я хочу об этом рассказать, а где писать, так, чтобы это читалось (и находилось поисковиками), не знаю. Пробовал завести блог,  но поисковики его не находят. Так что продолжать его вести просто опускаются руки. Может, кто-нибудь мне может что-нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: Habr? Но там статьи серьёзные, соответственно писать нужно с пользой для общества :)

Comment: На blogspot попробуйте - он гуглу принадлежит. Ближе некуда.

Comment: здесь и выкладывайте. в виде вопросо-ответа. просто к примеру: большинство [заданных мною здесь вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin?tab=questions) как раз и являются такими «вопросо-ответами».

Comment: Видеоуроки на ютуб, и в блоге продублировать

Comment: Шутить, вроде, не намерен, но там по-любому будет фильтр. Так что все не опубликуется. Так я на этом blogshop и пробовал, а тот блог как раз и не находится поисковиком.

Comment: >здесь и выкладывайте. в виде вопросо-ответа  
                                                                                  Будут модерировать, удалять... Морока.

Comment: На хабре публикуйте. Если нет инвайта, опубликуйте в песочницу и дайте ссыль, кину инвайт.

Comment: Suvitruf, и что, обязательно опубликуют?

Comment: @Grek79 если дадут инвайт, то да. Но статья должна быть по-настоящему хорошей, чтоб инвайт дали)

Comment: Зарегистрируйтесь в google webmaster tools и добавьте там свой сайт - тогда гугл точно до него доберется. То же самое для яндекса и бинга.

Comment: @Grek79 Я несколько лет начал писать блог об Oracle APEX. Это такая штука, по которой на русском языке информации очень мало. Я сделал два поста за два месяца на блогспоте, после чего мой блог выдавался на третьем месте по запросу "блог об Oracle APEX". Возможно, вы делаете что-то не так.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, можно попробовать здесь в форме вопросов-ответов.

TeX у нас всё-таки в тематике, IDE - тоже (хотя в данном случае речь не совсем про IDE). Только не надо сразу много вопросов публиковать - лучше ограничиться одним вопросом за некоторый промежуток времени (минимум день, может и реже).

Comment: речь **совсем** про ide.

Comment: >Будут модерировать, удалять... Морока<br/>[Как словом, так и делом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958097/lyx-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Вроде, и пошло хорошо и вот. Что делать, ума не приложу. Не хотят люди появления новой инфы в Инете и все тут! Вы же видите: человек хочет поделиться. Неужели нельзя закрыть глаза?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91264/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy---).

Comment: Тем не менее вопросы таки [закрывают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958097)