# Может, сделать новую метку [LyX]?

Tags: предложение, метки, создание-метки

Не добавить ли еще метку [lyx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lyx)? Прям, очень не хватает. Я намерен выкладывать инфу по этой программе, а как это отличить от [latex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex)?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91245/discussion-on-question-by-grek79-----lyx).

Answer (score 6):

Метка обычно не создаётся отдельно от вопроса. Более того, когда вопросов с определённой меткой становится ноль (например, при удалении вопросов, или при удалении отдельно метки с вопросов), метка тоже перестаёт существовать через некоторое время (вроде как сутки).

Затрудняюсь сказать, что происходит с описанием метки, наверное, его всё же можно будет потом ещё где-то выцепить. Но обычно, полезные метки не удаляются бесследно.

Поэтому, если нужно создать метку, пока у вас ещё нет [необходимых для этого привилегий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), создайте подходящий вопрос (указав пока что существующие метки, пусть и не совсем корректные), дождитесь позитивной реакции сообщества на вопрос/ответ, попросите (например, в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)) любого участника с достаточным уровнем репутации создать метку на упомянутом вопросе.

Comment: Если метка только на одном вопросе, то она тоже удаляется - вроде через полгода.

Comment: Во-первых, @αλεχολυτ, не для одной темы: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8816/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E, во-вторых, я вижу, что специфика этого форума такова, что позитивной реакции я не дождусь никогда: просто интересы участников этого форума слишком далеки от LaTeX, о LyX я вообще молчу. При этом я не хочу никого обидеть. Просто хочется поделиться инфой, чтоб не пропадала зря. Хотя ограниченное маленькое число символов в сообщении тоже может стать проблемой.

Comment: @Grek79 пишете вопрос + ответ, напишите в чат, вам поставят метку. Думаю всё. Дальше уже будете её использовать.